# Is this return written correctly Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is this return written correctly, here is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return 
    <?php

    // Log out when browser is closed
    echo "  location.href=\"/logout.php?task=EndLive&webcam_id=".$_GET['webcam_id']."\"";

    ?>
    ;
    });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

Is the return written correctly is there a proper way to writer it?

Comment: Keep in mind: Javascript is not Java.

Comment: I can't tell what it is supposed to do (why would you return a statement that assigns a value to location.href?), but it certainly isn't "right" . Aside from anything else, it contains a huge XSS hole.

Comment: mixing PHP and JavaScript is rarely a good idea, and often leads to confusion about server-side vs client-side code, but if you fully understand what's going on, you're probably OK, although it's not very elegant (and as pointed out, is a big code injection risk)

Comment: FYI, There's no reason to wait for `$(window).load()` to assign a handler to `window`. Clearly if the `window` is available to assign the `load` handler, then it's also available to assign the `beforeunload` handler.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* written correctly - and I can say this *without* caring what the actual result of the PHP is. (Although, for the sake of HTML/JavaScript-related questions, you should post the *actual* HTML/JS sent to the client.)

The problem is that `return` is a *restricted production* and will "insert an implicit semicolon too soon".

That is, these two are *different*:

```
function f() {
  return "x" // same line
}

function g() { 
  return    // newline after return - ASI kicks in!
  "x"       // this line is NEVER EXECTURED
}

f() // -> "x"
g() // -> undefined
```

At *best*, the PHP code will generate something that looks like the latter and thus be incorrect. *The `return` statement will terminate the function before `location.href` ever runs - and the browser location will not change!*

I would start by moving the `return` statement to the end of the function and supplying an appropriate value. (Also, if I recall, IE had quirks and should use event.value with *no* return in this case? YMMV.)

Of course, even with the above semantic syntax issue fixed, there may be other problems - but *one* issue at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, because in beforeunload you cannot redirect user to another page (javascript limitation) and the returned value must be string which browser will later show you as an alert.